# Mee6 Experience Lvl System Clone In NodeJS (Static Value?)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to replicate the Discord-Famous Discord Bot [Mee6](https://mee6bot.com/)'s Experience Algorithm in NodeJS (the OG Bot is in Python) but every attempt im stumped by static values.

```js
function XPValue(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
XPValue(15, 25) // This Randomizes as normal
const curLevel = Math.floor(0.5 * Math.sqrt(XPValue(15, 25))); //When put it here it becomes a static number and never changes
```

I don't understand how I can get the XP to randomize as I actually want it to do using the `XPValue` function, even though it's passed through that `function` it keeps a static value of `2`

Comment: Are you saying you want the number to change after it's been calculated?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get a random value of XP to give to a player based per execution of the script in question. @Lioness100

Comment: I still don't think I understand. If you just want to generate a random number, then what's going wrong? Are you getting the same number whenever you run the function?

Comment: I had a friend on plexidev help me on this matter gonna post the answer :) thanks for the help tho @Lioness100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was the variable once assign it wouldn't changed the value per execution where as using a getter fixed this issue:

```js
const Experience = {
    get random() {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
        return rand + (25 - 15);
    }
};
```

credits to Zelak (PlexiDev)